# How to prevent others for read /write on the file, while it is writing

Tags: linux, shell, perl, aix

I wanted to put a lock while one process is writing on the text file. so no other process can read or write.

Comment: You could try use [`flock`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html), but it will only work if the other processes also respect the lock

Comment: There is no mandatory file locking on Linux, so you cannot prevent other processes from accessing the file. You can only use cooperative locking, that means all affected processes have to use the same locking mechanism.

Comment: Aix or Linux? You have both OSes tagged...

Comment: Linux, at least, *kind* of has mandatory file locking, but it requires jumping through a lot of hoops to set up, is all but officially deprecated, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: An alternative is to write to a *temporary* file and then append to the original when your write is done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux flock, how to "just" lock a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388009/linux-flock-how-to-just-lock-a-file)

Comment: @Shawn it's for both AIX and linux

Answer (score 3):

The [`flock`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#flock) file locking mechanism in Perl is advisory. It can be used to exclude other processes from accessing a file **if those other processes are also using flock**. Even this mechanism will be flaky with some systems (I'm looking at *you*, NFS).

It may be more reliable to operate with an anonymous, temporary file that other processes will not know about, and to rename your file when you are done with it.

```
use File::Temp;

my ($fh, $obscure_filename) = tempfile();
print $fh "some data ...\n";
...
close $fh;
rename($obscure_filename, $the_real_name_of_the_file);
```