# Unable to lock file linux

Tags: linux, file, flock

I'm trying to lock a file and obviously there is something I'm missing, because eventhough it seems it's locked I can still access and edit it using vim editor.

Locking file:

```
flock -x lock2.txt sleep 30
```

Checking using lslocks:

```
COMMAND           PID  TYPE SIZE MODE  M START END PATH
flock            5417 FLOCK  10B WRITE 0     0   0 /home/lock2.txt
```

But still able to access it and edit using different terminal (different process I believe).
I tried the solution with file descriptors here
[Linux flock, how to "just" lock a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388009/linux-flock-how-to-just-lock-a-file)
but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flock` command uses `flock(2)` to lock the file. As the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) says

> `flock()` places advisory locks only; given suitable permissions on a file, a process is free to ignore the use of `flock()` and perform I/O on the file.

In general, applications don't check advisory locks. They're intended for use within a specific application to coordinate between multiple processes.

The `flock` command is most often used by a single application just to prevent itself from running multiple times concurrently.