# "grep -v" weird behavior

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to make sure my script only runs once at a time, but im running into weird behavior with inverting grep.

My Code:

```
echo "Current Pid: $$"
# Output "Current Pid: 5387"
echo "Process Count: $(pgrep -c -f "$0")"
# Output: Process Count: 2

if [ "$(pgrep -c -f "$0")" -gt 1 ]
then
    echo All Pids
    pgrep -f "$0"
    # Output "4978, 5387"

    echo Pids Current
    echo "$(pgrep -f "$0" |& grep -F $$)"
    # Output "5387"

    echo Pids Inverted
    echo "$(pgrep -f "$0" |& grep -Fv $$)"
    # Output "4978, 5394"

    # processPidsToKill="$(pgrep -f "$0" |& grep -Fv $$)"

    # for processPid in $processPidsToKill; do
    #     echo "Killing `basename "$0"` $processPid"
    #     kill "$processPid"
    # done
fi
```

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?
Where does the new Pid come from when im using "grep -v"?

Comment: Does this happen every time you run the script?

Comment: Because I'm thinking that another instance of the script might have started up between the commands.

Comment: Did you try doing `ps -p 5394` to see what's running there?

Comment: @Barmar yes, and just to be sure i tried it on a different system and got the same result. I dont think a new instand started, since i made a new script and started it twice my self. Also the new Pid sometimes no longer existed when it tried to kill it.

Comment: Keep in mind that `$$` gives you only the PID of the parent shell, not that of any subshell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why would that matter here? The current shell (running this script) is what they want to exclude.

Comment: @Barmar, they've got a command substitution with a pipeline in it. `$BASHPID`  is going to be different from `$$`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `$$` inside a command substitution is the original shell, not the subshell.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. The pipeline is still running when all this happens.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, I see. `pgrep` excludes itself, but it doesn't exclude the subshell created to exexute the `$(...)`, which has the same name as the original shell. I guess you should write that as an answer.

Comment: I'm not comfortable bringing that up to the level of an answer without some testing I don't have time to do right now (Q: does `grep -Ev "^($$|$BASHPID)\$"` suffice, or does that still leave the other pipeline component's subshell unhandled?), but yes, that's an accurate statement of my theory of the problem.

Comment: @PandaSITT, ...to be clear, in general, I consider any use of pgrep a code smell / indication that someone is doing something wrong. If you're doing process supervision correctly it tends to be generally unnecessary because you can just tell systemd to kill the whole cgroup for your service (or equivalent in whatever other framework you're using).

Comment: @PandaSITT, ...when that's not an option for whatever reason I typically use a file handle to tag processes that might need to be selected and killed -- `exec {lockfile_fd}>/path/to/tempfile` before starting your background process, and then `fuser -k /path/to/tempfile` to kill every process with a handle on that file; much more reliable than going by name, and it lets you have multiple sets of processes and address them individually as long as each one uses a different lockfile.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Its more then possible that im doing something wrong, i never really used Bash Script before. Im guessing the new Pid is a Subprocess ever grep or pgrep. Its done running imideatlly after that line of code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, scrapping my code and im following [this](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex) guid

Comment: Nothing wrong with that guide (in general, the bash-hackers' wiki is a great resource), but if you're only targeting Linux you might think about using `fuser` (which is mentioned there, but not demonstrated). The answer on this site to [Linux flock: How to "just" lock a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388009/linux-flock-how-to-just-lock-a-file) is a little on the complicated side as demonstrations go (given that the OP there asked for something that was deceptively complicated); for something simpler, you might just look at the usage pattern shown in `man flock`.