# File descriptor from flock put in a variable is not found when releasing it with exec

Tags: bash, exec, flock

I'm trying to get a lock on a file with bash. I've found some docs, including this nice answer:

[Linux flock, how to "just" lock a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388009/linux-flock-how-to-just-lock-a-file#answer-24389468)

It works, **BUT** I cannot release the file descriptor using a variable.

This WORKS

```bash
LOCK_FILE="lock.lock"
# Acquire lock - lock_fd is always 10 in my machine
exec {lock_fd}>$LOCK_FILE || exit 1
flock "$lock_fd" || exit 1
# Release lock - OK
exec 10>&-
```

See the last line to release the lock: `exec 10>&-`. If I put the number it works

BUT, this DOES NOT work:

```bash
LOCK_FILE="lock.lock"
# Acquire lock
exec {lock_fd}>$LOCK_FILE || exit 1
flock "$lock_fd" || exit 1
# Release lock - not found
exec $lock_fd>&-
```

I use the variable `exec $lock_fd>&-`, as shown in the answer above (and in some other documentation I've found around)

```
./lock.sh: line 6: exec: 10: not found
```

Somebody could tell what is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Use `eval "exec $lock_fd>&-"`

Comment: Simpler: `exec {lock_fd}>&-`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, `exec {lock_fd}>&-` works perfectly